# Why is my image mask not working on an NSSegmentedControl?

Tags: cocoa

Im trying to mimic Xcode's left panel icon : blue when selected, dark when unselected : [image: screenshot]

I have a pdf file with my image, I add it to images.xcassets as "vector" and "Render as template". However this doesn't work : here is how it looks
[image] and [image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the default behaviour of NSSegmentedCell.You can subclass NSSegmentedCell and override the draw.